# how to render a polymer element on a click of the row in paper-datatable?

Tags: event-handling, rendering, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

I am using a paper-datatable in my polymer element. It has some 10-50 rows. Each row containing the name of the employee & dateOfJoining & Designation. On click of any row ( i.e any employee ) , I want to render another polymer element which shows the details of that employee (more like past data). 
How can I achieve this ? How can I use < cust-details > inside an event handler method associated with the click ?

Answer (score 3):

From [paper-datatable event docs](http://david-mulder.github.io/paper-datatable/components/paper-datatable/demo/miscellaneous/events.html),  use row-tap.

Then make a call:

```
on-row-tap="show_emploee_dateils"
```

Inside that function:

```
show_emploee_dateils: function (element, ev) {

    console.log(element);
    console.log(ev);

   // ev.item holds the employee object, make it a property
   this.employee_details = ev.item;

   //show the element with details, as: paper-dialog, or dom-if template...
   this.show_details = true;

},
```

Template would be as:

```
<template id="employee_details" is="dom-if" if="{{show_details}}">
  <div>{{employee_details}}</div>
</template>
```

That are the basic lines, of course there a details to consider too.